# Investigate convergence of a series $ \sum_{n=1 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}-1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am supposed to investigate convergence of a series $  \sum_{n=1 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}-1} $ . I decided that the series converge to 0, because it clearly visible from first 5 elements. To do a proof, I used limit comparison test with $\sum_{n=1 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}} $  . Is my solution correct? Thanks

Comment: The series most certainly does not converge to zero, as all of its terms are positive. That being said, your application of the limit comparison test is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's right when you change the sequence (for example compare it with $1\over (1.5)^n$). You may also apply ratio test as following $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{a_{n+1}\over a_n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}{2^{n}-1\over 2^{n+1}-1}={1\over 2}<1$$therefore the series converges though not to zero.

Comment: I think it is right but not with the sequence the OP exemplified.....

Comment: It is OK.......

Answer (score 2):

Yes we can use limit comparison test indeed

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2^{n}-1}}{\frac{1}{2^{n}}}=\frac{2^n}{2^{n}-1}\to 1$$

As an alternative since for $n\ge 1$

$$\frac{1}{2^{n}-1}\le\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

then

$$\sum_{n=1 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}-1}=1+\sum_{n=2 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}-1} \le 1+\sum_{n=2 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=1+\sum_{n=1 }^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is correct: the general term of your series
$$\frac1{2^n-1}\sim_{n\to \infty}\frac1{2^n}$$
in the sense of *asymptotic analysis, i.e. $ \;\dfrac{\tfrac1{2^n-1}}{\frac1{2^n}} $ tends to $1$ as $n\to\infty$, and two series with equivalent (positive) general term both converge or both diverge.

Answer (score 1):

The series is absolutely convergent by comparison with a geometric series. We may notice that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\sum_{k\geq 1}2^{-kn} = \sum_{m\geq 1}\frac{d(m)}{2^m}=\frac{25}{16}+\sum_{m\geq 7}\frac{d(m)}{2^m} $$
and since for any $m\geq 7$ we have $2\leq d(m) \leq \frac{m}{2}$ it follows that
$$ \frac{51}{32}\leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n-1}\leq \frac{13}{8} $$
so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2^n-1}=\frac{103}{64}+E,\qquad |E|\leq\frac{1}{64}. $$